# How to remove a mask region in the image?

Tags: c++, opencv

Here are two example images. The left is an image with some seals and the middle is the sealed mask image I got in advance. What I want is to remove the seals from the image perfectly. I've tried to set the pixel values of the mask region to [255, 255, 255] and `inpaint` function in OpenCV, but they won't always give me acceptable results.

[example_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlcUn.jpg)
[example_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzRAw.jpg)

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify you want to produce an image as if the pages had never been stamped. So the black lettering is still visible under the inked regions? Since the stamped seals are a different color to everything else in the image you may not need the masks at all. Let me know and I will post some suggestions.

Comment: Yes, I don't need the masks at all, but the stamped seals are not always a different color to everything else in the image. For instance, there may exist red seals and red texts meanwhile. @PeteBlackerThe3rd

Comment: I can see a solution if the text is a clearly different color to the seal, however if the seal is the same color as the text underneath it then your task has become pretty much impossible.

Comment: What I mean is the seal is red, and there are red texts somewhere else in the image, not underneath the seal in most cases. Let's assume the text is a clearly different color to the seal first and what solution could be?

Comment: using hsv you can detect colors https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0IPYlIK-4A

Comment: The problem now is I can get the seals mask and how can I remove them from the image like they don't exist?